# Make absolutely positioned div get dimensions of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with multiple widgets which each display data from different services.

I want to set a loading overlay on each widget independently when the data for that specific widget is being loaded. The widgets don't have a set height or width. I am using Bootstrap's grid to structure the layout.

Basically, once I need to load data, I'm appending another div with opacity to the widget root div, and positioning it absolutely with top/left 0.

The width and the height of the overlay are currently calculated using jQuery's `innerWidth` method on the widget root div. This makes the overlay the same size as the actual widget.

My problem is that when I resize the page while the overlay is being shown, its width and height are not recalculated, while the widget dimensions are. I end up with an overlay div that is larger than its parent.

Is there any way I can solve this using CSS alone (i.e. without binding to a resize event)?
I need to support Chrome, Firefox and IE9+, so I'm open for any modern techniques.

Comment: *"and positioning it absolutely with top/left 0."* Then why not also `right` and `bottom`?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I've done that so many times, I can't believe I missed it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just try `%` on the overlay without the Jquery function :

```
.overlay {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```